# Auto blog creation in a WordPress multisite environment

Tags: wordpress, plugins, registration

I'm looking for a way to have users register on a multisite setup and have a blog automatically created for them... no, not the way the standard ms registration system handles it. I want to get rid of the second step in the process completely. They register as 'user', and a blog is automatically created at http://my.site.com/user for them.

Followup question... anyone know of a way of automatically pruning the multisite platform? IE, users who don't login for 'x' timeframe (or after a certain time period has elapsed) automatically have their site deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just make one pure copy of Wordpress files and database layout just after wordpress instalation. When you will have it, after user complete registration just copy files from original directory like "_original_wordpress" to "username_dir", and create new database or just add tables with username_ prefix in them. Also you have to cofigure config.php or whatever there is in wordpress that contains database data.

As for 2nd problem - use CRON. Write script in PHP that lists all users who was last active before month ago, delete tables from database in MySQL and dir "/username/" and it's gone :) And so that it would be executed regulary, just put it in CRON like every day once?

Well thats just one of the way to solve any of your problems but it look very simple.